# Locating variables a and b in a phase lead compensation system

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, gain

I have a block diagram that looks like this:

[image]

I am asked to find the **maximum angular frequency** of the **phase lead compensation**, thus, in order to locate values a and b, I first find the maximum phase lead frequency below

$$
  \begin{align*}
        & C(s) = \dfrac{bs+1}{as+1}, \quad C(jω) = \dfrac{jbω+1}{jaω+1} \\
        & ϕ(ω) = \tan^{-1}(bω) - \tan^{-1}(aω) \\
        & ϕ'(ω) = \dfrac{b}{1 + (bω)^2} - \dfrac{a}{1 + (aω)^2} = 0, \space (b-a) = (b-   a)ω^2ab \\
        & ω_m = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}
    \end{align*}
$$

Now, I am given the information that after combining C(s) and P(s), the **gain cross frequency** is $$ω_{G} = ω_{m} = 5 rad/s$$

Therefore, I have tried to find the frequency when **gain margin** is equal to **1** this way,

$$
  P(jω)C(jω) = \dfrac{(jbω+1)5\sqrt{7}}{{(jaω+1})(jω+\sqrt{3})jω} \\
  |P(jω)C(jω)| = \dfrac{5\sqrt{7}\sqrt{1+(bω)^2}}{ω(\sqrt{1+(aω)^2})(\sqrt{3+ω^2})} = 1
$$

$$
  \begin{cases} ab = \dfrac{1}{25} \\ 175(1+(bω_G)^2) = {ω_G^2(1+(aω_G)^2)(3+ω_G^2)} \ \end{cases}
$$

However, from the result I got:

$$
   a = \dfrac{1}{10}, b = \dfrac{2}{5} \\
   a = -\dfrac{1}{10}, b = -\dfrac{2}{5} 
$$

I am not sure which one should be the suitable one.